# How to find wordpress post id from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, join

I have a wordpress database and I want to get some data from that. In fact I want to get posts export to excell file. Now I want to join wp_posts and wp_postmeta and get a export. I find post_id in wp_postmeta  table but I cant any key with this value in wp_posts.

thanks.

Comment: `join using wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id`

Comment: **wp_posts.id** is **AUTO_INCREMENT** and we have more than a row that point to a special post. so it's not good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click on edit button on post, open inspect element with firebug and you can see id there or just off permalink view post and you can see the post_id in url.